# spresenseのRAMの使用領域を拡大する方法はあるのでしょうか

Tags: spresense, arduino

お世話になります。
Arduino IDEを使ってspresenseのプログラムにチャレンジしています。
コンパイルした時に、spresenseのメインメモリは1.5MBのはずなのに、半分ほどしか使われていないことに気づきました。
デフォルト設定のようです。
また、プログラムが大きくなると動作不安定や書き込めないことが起こるようです。
せっかく1.5MBあるので、有効利用したいのですが、使用領域を変更する方法がわかりません。
プログラム書き込みの領域を変更する方法はあるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

今後、spresenseがバージョンアップされて、メインメモリが大きくなればいいなと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino IDEの場合、メモリエリアの半分を共有メモリと呼んで、
SubCoreなどに使うようになっているようです。

MulitiCoreのライブラリを使うことで、このエリアを使用るすることができます。

ここを参照すると良いようです。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_mp_library

MP.AllocSharedMemory()
で共有メモリからメモリのエリアをとることができます。

ここに、画像や音声、センサデータや、AIのnnbなどのファイルを置くことで、
かなりのメモリを削減できるようなります。

ご参考になれば。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

[Spresense Arduino v2.0.1](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/release_arduino_ja.html#_v2_0_1_20200616) にて、メモリサイズを変更する機能が追加されています。

MainCoreに割り当てるメモリサイズを、デフォルト756KBから最大1.5MBまで拡張することができます。

手順については、[Arduinoメモリサイズ変更](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_tutorial_memory_config) をご確認ください。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム